# Show PNotify notification on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, pnotify

I have a page in which I want to display a notification using **PNotify**. How do I display a notification on this page using the **PNotify**-javascript library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the PNotify [documentation](https://sciactive.com/pnotify/#page):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (new PNotify({
        title: 'Regular Notice,
        text: 'Check me out! I\'m a notice.',
        type: 'info',
        styling: 'bootstrap3'
    }));
});
```